# Is there any way I could get a browser notification from the spring-boot backend?

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I am developing an app which has a spring-boot backend and angular-8 frontend. There is a requirement to implement a browser push notification when a batch process is returned from the backend. for example when a query is run to sort some parameters like female candidates from a table that contains 25,000 entities. when the process is done, the backend has to send a browser notification. Is there any direct way to implement it, or any workaround, any references, or threats I should follow? I have looking for a solution for days. I couldn't find any! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you have a look at websockets? Currently your question is too broad for this site, so it will likely be closed, but if you have a specific problem when trying to implement e.g. websockets, feel free to ask another question.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events

Comment: Thank you, ill look into it